# Micronaut + gorm + standalone - Error encoding object - No session found

Tags: hibernate, grails, grails-orm, micronaut

I am trying to use Micronaut with Gorm Standalone with no luck. I have a multiproject gradle configuration. One project contains the domain classes and the other is the api project.

I get this error when I try to save the instance (I think the error is thrown when trying to encode it to json with Jackson): `ERROR i.m.h.s.netty.RoutingInBoundHandler - Unexpected error occurred: Error encoding object [test.Laboratory : 1] to JSON: Could not obtain current Hibernate Session; nested exception is org.hibernate.HibernateException: No Session found for current thread (through reference chain: test.Laboratory["attached"])`

The whole project has this structure:

```
- Root
-- Api
-- Domain classes
```

**Root project**

The root project has this `settings.gradle` file:

```
include 'api'
include 'domain'

rootProject.name = 'medications'
```

**Domain project**

`settings.gradle`

```
rootProject.name = 'domain'
```

`gradle.properties`

```
micronautVersion=1.2.9
```

`build.gradle`

```
plugins {
    id 'groovy'
}

dependencies {
    compile 'org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-all:2.5.6'
    implementation "io.micronaut.configuration:micronaut-hibernate-validator"
    compile 'io.micronaut.configuration:micronaut-hibernate-gorm'
    implementation "org.grails:grails-datastore-gorm-hibernate5:7.0.1.RELEASE"

    runtime 'org.apache.tomcat:tomcat-jdbc'
    runtime  'com.h2database:h2'

    compileOnly platform("io.micronaut:micronaut-bom:$micronautVersion")
    compileOnly "io.micronaut:micronaut-inject-groovy"
    implementation platform("io.micronaut:micronaut-bom:$micronautVersion")

    testCompileOnly platform("io.micronaut:micronaut-bom:$micronautVersion")
    testImplementation platform("io.micronaut:micronaut-bom:$micronautVersion")
    testImplementation("org.spockframework:spock-core") {
        exclude group: "org.codehaus.groovy", module: "groovy-all"
    }
    testImplementation "io.micronaut:micronaut-inject-groovy"
    testImplementation "io.micronaut.test:micronaut-test-spock"
    testImplementation "io.micronaut.test:micronaut-test-junit5"
    testRuntimeOnly "org.junit.vintage:junit-vintage-engine:5.5.0"
}

repositories {
    jcenter()
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url "https://jcenter.bintray.com" }
}
```

Inside `src/main/groovy/test`:

```
package test

import grails.gorm.annotation.Entity
import org.grails.datastore.gorm.GormEntity

@Entity
class Laboratory implements GormEntity<Laboratory> {
    String name
}
```

**Api**

`settings.gradle`

```
rootProject.name="api"
```

`gradle.properties`

```
micronautVersion=1.2.9
```

`build.gradle`

```
plugins {
    id "groovy"
    id "io.spring.dependency-management" version "1.0.6.RELEASE"
    id "com.github.johnrengelman.shadow" version "5.2.0"
    id "application"
}

version "0.1"
group "medications.api"

apply plugin:"application"
apply plugin:"groovy"

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url "https://jcenter.bintray.com" }
}

configurations {
    developmentOnly 
}

dependencies {
    compile 'org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-all:2.5.6'

    compile project(':domain')

    implementation "io.micronaut.configuration:micronaut-hibernate-validator"
    compile 'io.micronaut.configuration:micronaut-hibernate-gorm'
    implementation "org.grails:grails-datastore-gorm-hibernate5:7.0.1.RELEASE"

    runtime "org.apache.tomcat:tomcat-jdbc:8.5.0"
    runtime "org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-logging-log4j:8.5.0"
    runtime "org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.10"
    runtime  'com.h2database:h2'

    compileOnly platform("io.micronaut:micronaut-bom:$micronautVersion")
    compileOnly "io.micronaut:micronaut-inject-groovy"
    implementation platform("io.micronaut:micronaut-bom:$micronautVersion")
    implementation "io.micronaut:micronaut-http-client"
    implementation 'io.micronaut:micronaut-http-server-netty'
    implementation "io.micronaut:micronaut-runtime-groovy"
    implementation "io.micronaut:micronaut-validation"
    runtime 'org.postgresql:postgresql:42.2.4'
    runtimeOnly "ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:1.2.3"
    testCompileOnly platform("io.micronaut:micronaut-bom:$micronautVersion")
    testImplementation platform("io.micronaut:micronaut-bom:$micronautVersion")
    testImplementation("org.spockframework:spock-core") {
        exclude group: "org.codehaus.groovy", module: "groovy-all"
    }
    testCompileOnly "io.micronaut:micronaut-inject-groovy"
    testImplementation "io.micronaut:micronaut-inject-groovy"
    testImplementation "io.micronaut.test:micronaut-test-spock"
    testImplementation "io.micronaut.test:micronaut-test-junit5"
    testImplementation "org.grails:grails-datastore-gorm-hibernate5"
    testRuntimeOnly "org.junit.vintage:junit-vintage-engine:5.5.0"
}

test.classpath += configurations.developmentOnly

mainClassName = "test.Application"

shadowJar {
    mergeServiceFiles()
}

run.classpath += configurations.developmentOnly
run.jvmArgs('-noverify', '-XX:TieredStopAtLevel=1', '-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote')
tasks.withType(GroovyCompile) {
    groovyOptions.forkOptions.jvmArgs.add('-Dgroovy.parameters=true')
}
```

`src/main/resources/application.yml`

```
---
micronaut:
  application:
    name: api

---
datasources.default: {}
---
hibernate:
  hbm2ddl:
    auto: create

dataSource:
  url: jdbc:postgresql://${db.host}:${db.port}/${db.name}
  dbCreate: create-drop
  driverClassName: org.postgresql.Driver
  username: ${db.username}
  password: ${db.password}
  dialect: POSTGRES
```

`LaboratoryController.groovy`

```
package test.controllers

import grails.gorm.transactions.Transactional
import io.micronaut.http.annotation.Controller
import io.micronaut.http.annotation.Post
import test.Laboratory
import test.services.LaboratoryService

@Controller("/laboratory")
@Transactional
class LaboratoryController {
    final LaboratoryService laboratoryService

    LaboratoryController(LaboratoryService laboratoryService) {
        this.laboratoryService = laboratoryService
    }


    @Post("/")
    Laboratory save(Laboratory laboratory) {
        return laboratoryService.save(laboratory)
    }
}
```

`LaboratoryService.groovy`

```
package test.services

import grails.gorm.services.Service
import groovy.transform.CompileStatic
import test.Laboratory

@Service(Laboratory)
@CompileStatic
abstract class LaboratoryService {
    abstract Laboratory save(Laboratory laboratory)
}
```

Error stack:

```
api_1      | 03:35:43.195 [pool-2-thread-3] ERROR i.m.h.s.netty.RoutingInBoundHandler - Unexpected error occurred: Error encoding object [test.Laboratory : 1] to JSON: Could not obtain current Hibernate Session; nested exception is org.hibernate.HibernateException: No Session found for current thread (through reference chain: test.Laboratory["attached"])
api_1      | io.micronaut.http.codec.CodecException: Error encoding object [test.Laboratory : 1] to JSON: Could not obtain current Hibernate Session; nested exception is org.hibernate.HibernateException: No Session found for current thread (through reference chain: test.Laboratory["attached"])
api_1      |    at io.micronaut.jackson.codec.JsonMediaTypeCodec.encode(JsonMediaTypeCodec.java:176)
api_1      |    at io.micronaut.jackson.codec.JsonMediaTypeCodec.encode(JsonMediaTypeCodec.java:182)
api_1      |    at io.micronaut.http.server.netty.RoutingInBoundHandler.encodeBodyAsByteBuf(RoutingInBoundHandler.java:1351)
api_1      |    at io.micronaut.http.server.netty.RoutingInBoundHandler.encodeBodyWithCodec(RoutingInBoundHandler.java:1297)
api_1      |    at io.micronaut.http.server.netty.RoutingInBoundHandler.lambda$subscribeToResponsePublisher$14(RoutingInBoundHandler.java:1232)
api_1      |    at io.micronaut.http.server.netty.RoutingInBoundHandler$$Lambda$619.00000000B80B9630.apply(Unknown Source)
api_1      |    at io.reactivex.internal.operators.flowable.FlowableMap$MapSubscriber.onNext(FlowableMap.java:63)
api_1      |    at io.micronaut.reactive.rxjava2.InstrumentedSubscriber.lambda$onNext$0(InstrumentedSubscriber.java:80)
api_1      |    at io.micronaut.reactive.rxjava2.InstrumentedSubscriber$$Lambda$635.0000000084161B60.run(Unknown Source)
api_1      |    at io.micronaut.reactive.rxjava2.InstrumentedSubscriber.onNext(InstrumentedSubscriber.java:84)
api_1      |    at io.reactivex.internal.operators.flowable.FlowableSwitchMap$SwitchMapSubscriber.drain(FlowableSwitchMap.java:307)
api_1      |    at io.reactivex.internal.operators.flowable.FlowableSwitchMap$SwitchMapInnerSubscriber.onSubscribe(FlowableSwitchMap.java:366)
api_1      |    at io.micronaut.reactive.rxjava2.InstrumentedSubscriber.onSubscribe(InstrumentedSubscriber.java:75)
api_1      |    at io.reactivex.internal.operators.flowable.FlowableJust.subscribeActual(FlowableJust.java:34)
api_1      |    at io.reactivex.Flowable.subscribe(Flowable.java:14918)
api_1      |    at io.reactivex.Flowable.subscribe(Flowable.java:14865)
api_1      |    at io.micronaut.reactive.rxjava2.RxInstrumentedCallableFlowable.subscribeActual(RxInstrumentedCallableFlowable.java:65)
api_1      |    at io.reactivex.Flowable.subscribe(Flowable.java:14918)
api_1      |    at io.reactivex.Flowable.subscribe(Flowable.java:14865)
api_1      |    at io.reactivex.internal.operators.flowable.FlowableSwitchMap$SwitchMapSubscriber.onNext(FlowableSwitchMap.java:129)
api_1      |    at io.micronaut.reactive.rxjava2.InstrumentedSubscriber.lambda$onNext$0(InstrumentedSubscriber.java:80)
api_1      |    at io.micronaut.reactive.rxjava2.InstrumentedSubscriber$$Lambda$635.0000000084161B60.run(Unknown Source)
api_1      |    at io.micronaut.reactive.rxjava2.InstrumentedSubscriber.onNext(InstrumentedSubscriber.java:84)
api_1      |    at io.reactivex.internal.operators.flowable.FlowableSubscribeOn$SubscribeOnSubscriber.onNext(FlowableSubscribeOn.java:97)
api_1      |    at io.micronaut.reactive.rxjava2.InstrumentedSubscriber.lambda$onNext$0(InstrumentedSubscriber.java:80)
api_1      |    at io.micronaut.reactive.rxjava2.InstrumentedSubscriber$$Lambda$635.0000000084161B60.run(Unknown Source)
api_1      |    at io.micronaut.reactive.rxjava2.InstrumentedSubscriber.onNext(InstrumentedSubscriber.java:84)
api_1      |    at io.micronaut.http.context.ServerRequestTracingPublisher$1.lambda$onNext$1(ServerRequestTracingPublisher.java:60)
api_1      |    at io.micronaut.http.context.ServerRequestTracingPublisher$1$$Lambda$636.0000000084166AD0.run(Unknown Source)
api_1      |    at io.micronaut.http.context.ServerRequestContext.with(ServerRequestContext.java:52)
api_1      |    at io.micronaut.http.context.ServerRequestTracingPublisher$1.onNext(ServerRequestTracingPublisher.java:60)
api_1      |    at io.micronaut.http.context.ServerRequestTracingPublisher$1.onNext(ServerRequestTracingPublisher.java:52)
api_1      |    at io.reactivex.internal.util.HalfSerializer.onNext(HalfSerializer.java:45)
api_1      |    at io.reactivex.internal.subscribers.StrictSubscriber.onNext(StrictSubscriber.java:97)
api_1      |    at io.micronaut.reactive.rxjava2.InstrumentedSubscriber.lambda$onNext$0(InstrumentedSubscriber.java:80)
api_1      |    at io.micronaut.reactive.rxjava2.InstrumentedSubscriber$$Lambda$635.0000000084161B60.run(Unknown Source)
api_1      |    at io.micronaut.reactive.rxjava2.InstrumentedSubscriber.onNext(InstrumentedSubscriber.java:84)
api_1      |    at io.reactivex.internal.operators.flowable.FlowableSwitchIfEmpty$SwitchIfEmptySubscriber.onNext(FlowableSwitchIfEmpty.java:59)
api_1      |    at io.micronaut.reactive.rxjava2.InstrumentedSubscriber.lambda$onNext$0(InstrumentedSubscriber.java:80)
api_1      |    at io.micronaut.reactive.rxjava2.InstrumentedSubscriber$$Lambda$635.0000000084161B60.run(Unknown Source)
api_1      |    at io.micronaut.reactive.rxjava2.InstrumentedSubscriber.onNext(InstrumentedSubscriber.java:84)
api_1      |    at io.reactivex.internal.operators.flowable.FlowableMap$MapSubscriber.onNext(FlowableMap.java:68)
api_1      |    at io.micronaut.reactive.rxjava2.InstrumentedSubscriber.lambda$onNext$0(InstrumentedSubscriber.java:80)
api_1      |    at io.micronaut.reactive.rxjava2.InstrumentedSubscriber$$Lambda$635.0000000084161B60.run(Unknown Source)
api_1      |    at io.micronaut.reactive.rxjava2.InstrumentedSubscriber.onNext(InstrumentedSubscriber.java:84)
api_1      |    at io.reactivex.internal.operators.flowable.FlowableCreate$NoOverflowBaseAsyncEmitter.onNext(FlowableCreate.java:403)
api_1      |    at io.micronaut.http.server.netty.RoutingInBoundHandler.lambda$buildResultEmitter$17(RoutingInBoundHandler.java:1422)
api_1      |    at io.micronaut.http.server.netty.RoutingInBoundHandler$$Lambda$607.00000000B80AA660.subscribe(Unknown Source)
api_1      |    at io.reactivex.internal.operators.flowable.FlowableCreate.subscribeActual(FlowableCreate.java:71)
api_1      |    at io.reactivex.Flowable.subscribe(Flowable.java:14918)
api_1      |    at io.reactivex.Flowable.subscribe(Flowable.java:14865)
api_1      |    at io.micronaut.reactive.rxjava2.RxInstrumentedFlowable.subscribeActual(RxInstrumentedFlowable.java:68)
api_1      |    at io.reactivex.Flowable.subscribe(Flowable.java:14918)
api_1      |    at io.reactivex.internal.operators.flowable.FlowableMap.subscribeActual(FlowableMap.java:37)
api_1      |    at io.reactivex.Flowable.subscribe(Flowable.java:14918)
api_1      |    at io.reactivex.Flowable.subscribe(Flowable.java:14865)
api_1      |    at io.micronaut.reactive.rxjava2.RxInstrumentedFlowable.subscribeActual(RxInstrumentedFlowable.java:68)
api_1      |    at io.reactivex.Flowable.subscribe(Flowable.java:14918)
api_1      |    at io.reactivex.internal.operators.flowable.FlowableSwitchIfEmpty.subscribeActual(FlowableSwitchIfEmpty.java:32)
api_1      |    at io.reactivex.Flowable.subscribe(Flowable.java:14918)
api_1      |    at io.reactivex.Flowable.subscribe(Flowable.java:14865)
api_1      |    at io.micronaut.reactive.rxjava2.RxInstrumentedFlowable.subscribeActual(RxInstrumentedFlowable.java:68)
api_1      |    at io.reactivex.Flowable.subscribe(Flowable.java:14918)
api_1      |    at io.reactivex.Flowable.subscribe(Flowable.java:14868)
api_1      |    at io.micronaut.http.context.ServerRequestTracingPublisher.lambda$subscribe$0(ServerRequestTracingPublisher.java:52)
api_1      |    at io.micronaut.http.context.ServerRequestTracingPublisher$$Lambda$620.0000000084013F10.run(Unknown Source)
api_1      |    at io.micronaut.http.context.ServerRequestContext.with(ServerRequestContext.java:52)
api_1      |    at io.micronaut.http.context.ServerRequestTracingPublisher.subscribe(ServerRequestTracingPublisher.java:52)
api_1      |    at io.reactivex.internal.operators.flowable.FlowableFromPublisher.subscribeActual(FlowableFromPublisher.java:29)
api_1      |    at io.reactivex.Flowable.subscribe(Flowable.java:14918)
api_1      |    at io.reactivex.Flowable.subscribe(Flowable.java:14865)
api_1      |    at io.micronaut.reactive.rxjava2.RxInstrumentedFlowable.subscribeActual(RxInstrumentedFlowable.java:68)
api_1      |    at io.reactivex.Flowable.subscribe(Flowable.java:14918)
api_1      |    at io.reactivex.Flowable.subscribe(Flowable.java:14865)
api_1      |    at io.reactivex.internal.operators.flowable.FlowableSubscribeOn$SubscribeOnSubscriber.run(FlowableSubscribeOn.java:82)
api_1      |    at io.reactivex.internal.schedulers.ExecutorScheduler$ExecutorWorker$BooleanRunnable.run(ExecutorScheduler.java:288)
api_1      |    at io.reactivex.internal.schedulers.ExecutorScheduler$ExecutorWorker.run(ExecutorScheduler.java:253)
api_1      |    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
api_1      |    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
api_1      |    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:825)
api_1      | Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Could not obtain current Hibernate Session; nested exception is org.hibernate.HibernateException: No Session found for current thread (through reference chain: test.Laboratory["attached"])
api_1      |    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException.wrapWithPath(JsonMappingException.java:394)
api_1      |    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException.wrapWithPath(JsonMappingException.java:353)
api_1      |    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.StdSerializer.wrapAndThrow(StdSerializer.java:316)
api_1      |    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:727)
api_1      |    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:155)
api_1      |    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.DefaultSerializerProvider._serialize(DefaultSerializerProvider.java:480)
api_1      |    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.DefaultSerializerProvider.serializeValue(DefaultSerializerProvider.java:319)
api_1      |    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._configAndWriteValue(ObjectMapper.java:3906)
api_1      |    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.writeValueAsBytes(ObjectMapper.java:3244)
api_1      |    at io.micronaut.jackson.codec.JsonMediaTypeCodec.encode(JsonMediaTypeCodec.java:173)
api_1      |    ... 79 common frames omitted
api_1      | Caused by: org.springframework.dao.DataAccessResourceFailureException: Could not obtain current Hibernate Session; nested exception is org.hibernate.HibernateException: No Session found for current thread
api_1      |    at org.grails.orm.hibernate.GrailsHibernateTemplate.getSession(GrailsHibernateTemplate.java:335)
api_1      |    at org.grails.orm.hibernate.GrailsHibernateTemplate.doExecute(GrailsHibernateTemplate.java:284)
api_1      |    at org.grails.orm.hibernate.GrailsHibernateTemplate.contains(GrailsHibernateTemplate.java:405)
api_1      |    at org.grails.orm.hibernate.AbstractHibernateGormInstanceApi.isAttached(AbstractHibernateGormInstanceApi.groovy:220)
api_1      |    at org.grails.datastore.gorm.GormEntity$Trait$Helper.isAttached(GormEntity.groovy:176)
api_1      |    at org.grails.datastore.gorm.GormEntity$Trait$Helper$isAttached$0.call(Unknown Source)
api_1      |    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:47)
api_1      |    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:115)
api_1      |    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:127)
api_1      |    at test.Laboratory.isAttached(Laboratory.groovy)
api_1      |    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
api_1      |    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
api_1      |    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
api_1      |    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
api_1      |    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:688)
api_1      |    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:719)
api_1      |    ... 85 common frames omitted
api_1      | Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: No Session found for current thread
api_1      |    at org.grails.orm.hibernate.GrailsSessionContext.currentSession(GrailsSessionContext.java:112)
api_1      |    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.getCurrentSession(SessionFactoryImpl.java:495)
api_1      |    at org.grails.orm.hibernate.GrailsHibernateTemplate.getSession(GrailsHibernateTemplate.java:333)
api_1      |    ... 100 common frames omitted
```

I already tried using `Laboratory.withNewSession{...}` but didn't work...

Created an issue for this: https://github.com/micronaut-projects/micronaut-groovy/issues/34

This is the repo containing the full example: https://github.com/mpccolorado/micronaut-gorm-standalone

Comment: FYI... There is no good reason for `LaboratoryController` to be marked with `@Transactional`.

Comment: That is because I am using DataServices, right @JeffScottBrown? It was another attempt to make it work. It is saving the object though but it seems that when trying to parse it to json is not able to get it

Comment: This may not help much, but I ran into this type of problem with proxies. The original read had a lazy-loaded proxy. I had to make sure the proxies were all resolved within the txn/session by reading them all from the DB.  The Micronaut non-blocking request handling is great, but it runs outside of the session/txn.  Usually in another  thread.  For this reason and some session/interceptor problems, I finally switched to Micronaut-Data.  As much as I love the GORM API, I came to hate the hibernate oddities.

Comment: Yes, that was a possible issue but the thing is that the entity has no associations, it has a single String property. For solving the issue that you had you need to do an eager fetch on the association on the query. If you are using Data Services you could use a @Join annotation.